# Do I have to stay the entire duration in Germany with a German Job Seeker Visa?

Tags: germany, working-visas

I am residing out of Germany at the time being and working a full-time job. However, I am planning to find a job in Germany and thus I am considering applying for Germany Job Seeker Visa.

As I am already working full-time, I cannot stay 6 months in Germany, thus I am planning to fly in and out intermittently to apply for jobs and attend interviews (if any). Is that acceptable on a Job Seeker Visa? And does it mean I only have to submit accommodation booking for the first period I am staying?

Answer (score 2):

§18c (Aufenthaltsgesetz) implies, indirectly, that if the person remains in the country for a specific amount of time: the visa can only be renewed when the foreigner has been outside the country the same amount of time that they were inside the country during the previous visa.

Since you are at present a full worker, I would suggest asking the Embassy/Counsulat how to look for work under such a constellation since §18c does not seem to be applicable.

One form of the question could be: can a tourist come for one for a job interview and then return back to his residence country until the next interview?

If you are a citizen of a country that needs a 90/180 visa, then could you apply for this for this purpose?